# Error when adding a document

Tags: solr

The SOLR schema has following fields:

```
   <!-- <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />  -->
   <field name="_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

   <!-- metadata used by mongo-connector -->
   <field name="_ts" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="ns" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />



   <!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error.
        alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default -->
   <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />

 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>_id</uniqueKey>
```

I am adding the following document:

> {"_id":"change.me","ns":"change.me", "_ts":123}

I get the following error:

> SolrCore org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to invoke
>   function processAdd in script: update-script.js:
>   sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (#71) in  at line number 71
>
> SolrDispatchFilter null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable
>   to invoke function processAdd in script: update-script.js:
>   sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (#71) in  at line number 71

What could be the problem? This is SOLR 5.3.0.

Comment: The error seems to come from an update processor that's invoked when a document is added. Try disabling any update processors and try again (the update-script.js reference)

Comment: http://localhost:9393/solr/eposro/update?wt=json content-type: json the cmd: {"add":{ "doc":{"_id":"change.me","ns":"change.me", "_ts":123},"boost":1.0,"overwrite":true,"commitWithin":1000}}   The operation I am trying to perform is an Addition of a document called using the update URL. If update processor is disabled, my functionality will not work. I am looking for an explanation on why a simple document does not get inserted in SOLR without any error message that explicitly points out the issue.

Comment: It does point it out - there's no function called "processAdd" in the script you've supplied.

Comment: I have not supplied it anything. This is all base functionality of SOLR.

Comment: Search for anything referencing update-script.js - you probably have a `<str name="script">update-script.js</str>` reference in your solrconfig for the update end point. I'm talking about removing that, not about removing the actual updateprocessor (I can see my naming was a bit off in the first comment).